# TypeError While Building String

Tags: python

```py
letters_count = len(name)
print("Your name consits of " + (letters_count) + " Letters long" )
```

I get this error every time I run it.

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear, have you tried looking up what it means?

Comment: This can be gettable on Google easily. Can you please do that once?

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate a string and an integer. It needs to be:

```
print("Your name consits of " + str(letters_count) + " Letters long" )
```